# How to make my buttons responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've a little problem with my buttons : http://jsfiddle.net/2B9XB/

Here is the css :

```
.button {
  background-color: #53a1b8;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3f8194;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  height: 3em;
  padding: .5em 2em .5em 2em; 
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #5eb6d0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #53a1b8;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

As you can see, there is a responsive problem, but i didn't find how to fix it. I want to  prevent the buttons on the bottom to hide those on the top.

Have you any idea ?

thanks,
Vinm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX :

Add `display:inline-block;` and remove `height:3em;` on `.button`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2B9XB/5/)**

Comment: I think the OP is looking to keep the buttons from breaking to the next line, perhaps a width needs to be applied as well.

Comment: @ChrisHardie I don't think so, the issue is that the buttons are overlapping each other when they break to a new line. the code I provided fixes that issue.

Comment: wouldn't an unordered list be called for here?

Comment: @ChrisM if you take it from a design point of view, it doesn't matter, if you take it from a semantic point of view, you are probably right (I don't know the content of those links and where they leed to)